# How to disable amCharts is skipping my data?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

amCharts is skipping data based on screen size. In picture I have a chart with 30 days but on bottom side you can see chart displays only every second label. How can I disable so all of the 30 day labels show?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The chart chooses appropriate amount of labels/grid lines to display based on chart size, so that category axis does not feel crammed and labels do not overlap.

You can disable this by setting [`autoGridCount: false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#autoGridCount) in `categoryAxis`. as well as [`gridCount: 31`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#gridCount). I.e.:

```
"categoryAxis": {
  // ...
  autoGridCount: false,
  gridCount: 31
}
```